# How do I tag a specific commit with GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I have created a simple script which uses GitPython to tag the latest commit on a specific branch which has already been checked out.

```
from git import Repo

def TagRepo(path, tag):
    repo = Repo(path)
    repo.create_tag(tag)
    repo.remotes.origin.push(tag)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage: %prog [options] ')
    parser.add_option('-p', '--path', dest='path', help='path to repo')
    parser.add_option('-t', '--tag', dest='tag', help='Tag label')

    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()

    TagRepo(options.path, options.tag)
```

I want to improve it so that I can pass it a specific commit's SHA and tag that instead of the latest commit on the branch but I can't see how to do that with GitPython.

Comment: If you are providing a specific SHA, why do you need the tag for? They can be used interchangeably

Comment: When i want to locate the commit (which relates to a release) down the line -
 I would rather be looking for version_1.2.3 than a11bef06a3f659402fe7563abf99ad00de2209e6.

Comment: Just a side note : do not make use of Optparse it is marked deprecated and is probably not included in py3.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of the [module](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#the-commit-object):

Obtain commits at the specified revision

```
    repo.commit('master')
    repo.commit('v0.8.1')
    repo.commit('HEAD~10')
```

So to retrieve a specific commit just use `repo.commit('SHA-1')`

Comment: Thanks I will try that.

Answer (score 0):

From the source code:

```
def create_tag(self, path, ref='HEAD', message=None, force=False, **kwargs)
```

it appears you can pass a ref to create_tag which following the comments down the line is described as:

> :param ref:
>               A reference to the object you want to tag. It can be a commit, tree or
>               blob.

so just get the commit you want and pass that as the ref. dont foget to push as OP does.